# Magento : Jirafe Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, module, extensions

I have Magento Extension Fooman_Jirafe.

- What is this module for?
- Is this module still used in magento 1 or 2 ?

Here is the module definition :

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Fooman_Jirafe>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Fooman_Jirafe>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Magento extension for Jirafe analytics. Get detailed business analytics in your email, and on your Magento dashboard. This plugin works with Magento Community 1.3 and above, and Magento Enterprise 1.9 and above. For more information, check out the wiki (cannot add a README file here because of the way plugins are installed in Magento) http://jirafe.com